# why does this function return all the objects in the array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass the argument name from the getAnimalByName function to the return value of the function nested in it. Why isn't it working correctly? Right now if I call getAnimalByName it will return all the objects in the animals array instead of just the one passed as the argument.

```
var animals=[
{type: 'mammal', subType: 'dog', name: 'spot', weight: 50},
    {type: 'reptile', subType: 'lizard', name: 'gicko', weight: 1},
    {type: 'reptile', subtype: 'snake', name: 'buba', weight: 3},
    {type: 'mammal', subType: 'rat', name: 'runner', weight: 3}
];
function getAnimalByName(name){
      var animal= animals.filter(function(event){
      return event.name;
    });
   return animal;
}
var spot= getAnimalByName('spot');
var gicko= getAnimalByName('gicko');
var buba= getAimalsByName('buba');
var runner= getAnimalByName('runner');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way filter works is within the function we need to specify, whether that particular array element matches a particular condition or not, so, internally the filter function is excepting a `truthy` or a `falsy` value, and since you returned `event.name`, it will always be a `truthy` value, and with that it pushes the values into a new array, hence it returned the entire the animals array.

So thats why you should have returned

`return event.name === name`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing condition in `Array#filter` handler function(`callback`)

```js
var animals = [{
  type: 'mammal',
  subType: 'dog',
  name: 'spot',
  weight: 50
}, {
  type: 'reptile',
  subType: 'lizard',
  name: 'gicko',
  weight: 1
}, {
  type: 'reptile',
  subtype: 'snake',
  name: 'buba',
  weight: 3
}, {
  type: 'mammal',
  subType: 'rat',
  name: 'runner',
  weight: 3
}];

function getAnimalByName(name) {
  return animals.filter(function(event) {
    return event.name === name; //Test value of argument here!
  });
}
var spot = getAnimalByName('spot');
var gicko = getAnimalByName('gicko');
var buba = getAnimalByName('buba');
var runner = getAnimalByName('runner');
console.log(spot);
console.log(gicko);
console.log(buba);
console.log(runner);
```